# Find $ad - bc$ if $ac = 18$ and $bd = 50$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a math problem to solve that goes as follows:

--

$(ax + by)(cx - dy)$

In the expression above, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are non-zero constants and $ad = bc$. If $ac = 18$ and $bd = 50$, what is the value of the coefficient of the $xy$ term when the expression is expanded and like terms are collected?

--

My work is below:

$(ax + by)(cx - dy)$ = $acx^2 - adxy + bcxy - bdy^2$

$xy$ term: $bcxy - adxy$

Therefore, all I need to find is $bc - ad$, right? I did this:

$bc - ad = 0$

$bc - (\frac{18}{c})(\frac{50}{b}) = 0$

$bc - \frac{900}{bc} = 0$

$b^2c^2 - 900 = 0$

$b^2c^2 = 900$

$bc = 30$

I did the same with $ad$, and got the result $ad = 30$ as well.
That would mean $bc - ad = 0$. It doesn't feel right, but my answer key does confirm the answer of $0$. If I use numbers other than $18$ and $50$, the answer still seems to come out to $0$. How is this possible?

Comment: You question is unclear. If you assume $ad=bc$ then of course $ad-bc=0$.

Comment: One of the things you wrote in your derivation is $bc-ad=0$.  This follows immediately from the assumption that $ad=bc$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the task is, so correct me if I'm wrong. You want to find the coefficient of the $xy$ term when the expresion $(ax+by)(cx-dy)$is expanded and you foun that coefficient is $bc-ad$, but you already know $bc=ad$, so what is the problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry guys, I didn't see that the question gave that ad = bc. I don't know what happened to me when I was solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When the polynomial is written out in expanded form, you get $$18x^2+(bc-ad)xy-50y^2.$$ It follows that if $bc=ad$ (as indeed you're given), then regardless of the values of $a,b,c$ and $d,$ we always have that the coefficient of $xy$ disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is $0$. Since you know $bc = ad$ and you also know that $xy = bc - ad$. Then it must be $0$. Since you're basically subtracting a number with itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same problem. If you assume that $x$ and $y$ are both $1$, it really clears things up and it becomes obvious that the coefficient is $bc - ad$, and $bc = ad$, so like @dennis21469 said, you are subtracting a number from it's self. The $18$ and $50$ are just there to confuse you.